# Method not allowed - correct route parameters flask

Tags: python, html, flask, web

When running my flask code, it tells me that my method is not allowed. I believe I have post in the proper location (in the app.route paramaters), but it's still telling me my method is not allowed.

Here is my code:

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template
    from flask_cors import CORS

    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)

    @app.route('/title',methods=['POST'])
    def title():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            title = request.json['title'] 
            return render_template('index.html')
        else:
            return "flawless"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='localhost',debug=True)
```

Client code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form">
        <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Name of Medium Article">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        const formEl = document.querySelector('.form');

        formEl.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(formEl);
            const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);

            fetch('http//:localhost:5000', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data)

        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Uncertain why it's telling me the method is not allowed - am I missing something?

Comment: What's the client code? Also, `return "flawless"""` should prevent this from even running, so make sure you're running the code you think you are.

Comment: Fixed flawless (forgot to delete comment from when I was debugging). I added client code to original post.

Comment: One discrepancy is you're posting to `/`, but the route is set up for `/title`.

Comment: I addressed that, but it’s still giving me the same error unfortunately